# Entity Framework Code First Three navigation properties of the same type in a class

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm modeling a class for a Birth Certificate, so I need that contains three properties of type Person for Father, Mother and Child.

```
public class Person 
{
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName1 { get; set; }
    public string LastName2 { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Person")]
    public virtual BirthCertificate BirthCertificate { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my class BirthCertificate

```
    public class BirthCertificate : EntityBase
        {
            public Guid BirthCertificateId { get; set; }
            public string BirthCertificateNumber { get; set; }
            public Guid PersonId {get;set;}
            public Guid FatherPersonId {get;set;}
            public Guid MotherPersonId {get;set;}
            public Person Person { get; set; }
            public Person Father{ get; set; }
            public Person Mother { get; set; }

        }
```

I'm not completely understanding the use of InverseProperty Annotation, so this schema trhows the exception below:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'Person' and 'BirthCertificate'. The principal end of this
>   association must be explicitly configured using either the
>   relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Anyone can help me please??

Answer (score 0):

Your inverse property use is correct, EF does not know which is the principal end of the configured relationship - that is, does the birth certificate belong to the person, or does the person belong to the birth certificate? EF will use this to determine insert ordering. Usually it simply uses any of the participiants with an nullable FK, but both of your FK's are not nullable.

Use data annotation [Required] for the navigation property, or with fluent API .HasRequiredPrincipal().WithRequiredDependant();

Comment: Thank you @DevilSuichiro, your advice gave me a starting point to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to  attemped the same target than me, I ended up solving the relation with Fluent this way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BirthCertificate>()
                .HasRequired(r => r.Person)      
                .WithMany()                        
                .HasForeignKey(r => r.PersonId)  
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<BirthCertificate>()
                .HasRequired(r => r.Father)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(r => r.FatherPersonId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<BirthCertificate>()
                .HasRequired(r => r.Mother)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(r => r.MotherPersonId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```